# use PullToRefreshExpandableListView with custom fragment

Tags: listview, android-fragments, pull-to-refresh

So i've just tried using the PulltoRefreshExpandableListView inside a custom fragment that extends Fragment, but when i try to set the adapter, here's the error:

mPullRefreshExpandableListView.setAdapter(adapter);

setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)
in PullToRefreshAdapterViewBase cannot be applied
to (sinfic.mobile.ipdms.adapters.GenericMultiColumnIconLineExpandableAdapter)

The GenericMultiColumn.... adapter extends BaseExpandableAdapter. What's the best solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
ExpandableListView actualListview = mPullRefreshExpandableListView.getRefreshableView();

actualListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```